# Extraction of optimal scores from clValid - subscript out of bounds

Tags: r, error-handling, cluster-analysis

I try to extract optimal scores from clValid package internal validation. For some datasets Model Based clustering algorithm is not able to define certain amounts of clusters. For the impossible number of clusters the package sets NAs for internal validation measures and in this case function optimalScores() doesn't work with the following error:

```
Error in which(x == min(x), arr.ind = TRUE)[1, ] : 
  subscript out of bounds
```

I know how to get optimal values from optimalScores() but it doesn't work. summary(intvalid) also provides the optimal scores however I could't find the way to extract them from the summary.

Example:

```
set.seed(199)
df1<-data.frame(replicate(4,sample(1:100,400,rep=TRUE)))

require(clValid)
intvalid <- clValid(df1, 2:10, clMethods=c("model"),
validation="internal", maxitems = 1000)

# doesn't work
optimalScores(intvalid)
# shows optimal scores
summary(intvalid)
```

How can I get the optimal scores despite NAs for some values?

Answer (score 0):

Did u try: 
intvalid <- clValid(df1, 2:10, clMethods="model",
validation="internal", maxitems = 1000)

I think if you use just one method you don't need the "c"